# Is it common in French magazines for the page numbers to include the cover and inside cover?

Tags: typographie

I have a French magazine from the 1980s that I am translating into English. The first page is labelled '3', meaning the front cover and inside cover page are obviously considered page 1 and 2 respectively.

Is this normal for French magazines, or, if not, a convention that died out at some point, or just a quirk of this particular publication?

Comment: I thought it was common practice, not just for French books? Every book I've ever read (as far as I know) counts the cover and the inside cover as page 1 and 2, not just magazine. With blank pages, content tables, etc., the first actual page is often something like page 9 or 11.

Answer (score 4):

Les trois magazines que je reçois font identiquement.

=> Ce n'est donc pas un *quirk*.

Je vois au contraire une *bonne* raison à cela :

- Contrairement aux livres, Il arrive que le verso de la couverture reçoive du contenu, contenu auquel peuvent d'ailleurs parfois renvoyer les tables des matières / illustrations.
- Sachant que, par convention remontant à loin dans l'histoire de l'imprimerie, les folios impairs sont, dans les pays où on lit de gauche à droite, réservés à la page de droite, le verso de la couverture, en tant que première page de contenu, ne peut pas prendre le numéro 1.

=> On prend pour le verso de la couverture, le plus petit numéro pair disponible : 2 => le recto de la page de droite prenant le numéro 3.

---

<sub>NDaCOSwt : En marge de cette question, on notera que dans le jargon de l'imprimerie, on appelle *folio* le numéro de page. Il donnera assez curieusement naissance au verbe *folioter* ainsi qu'à l'action correspondante de *foliotage* correspondant à ce que nous appelons vulgairement *paginer* / *pagination*</sub>